# Limiting user input to numerical values

Tags: c++, visual-c++, scanf

```
printf("\n Quais os valores da Matriz B? \n");
for (i = 0; i < n_linhas_B; i++)
{
   for (j = 0; j < n_colunas_B; j++)
   {
     printf("\n Elemento [%d][%d]", i, j);
     matriz_B[i][j] = ler_comp();
   }
}
printf("\n >");
```

I want it to only accept integer type input, and display an error message and loop back the question when the user inserts characters or symbols

Comment: Try writing `std::cin` instead of `cin` ...

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 is more than capable of recognizing `cin` as it's part of the standard since the very beginning of C++. You are doing something wrong, like not including the appropriate headers or not properly qualifying the identifiers.

Comment: Now that you know std::can and std::cout do in fact exist in the world of Visual Studio, make sure `#include <iostream>` is at the top of your file, use the std namespace, and see if you can figure it out. If you still need help, rewrite your question and be sure to include the code you've written so far so we are better able to help you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: the problem is not jsut the use of cin and cout, I can easily understand them and their use, the problem is when the answers involve other functions that vs seemingly doesn't take in and that I can't understand as I don't really work with them.

Comment: @ChuckNorris "_but they all use cin, cout and other functions that Visual Studio 2017 doesn't recognize._" 1) `cin`, and `cout` are objects, not functions. 2) Please provide [mcve], since I doubt your claims that Visual Studio 2017 fails to recognize such cornerstone objects of C++ language.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uCRjUK3F
I want to make sure that what the user inputs can't be a character or a symbol, if it is I want it to display an error message and ask the question again

Comment: @ChuckNorris Please post your code as part of your question instead of providing a link in a comment. Also you can always check the stream state, if something invalid was input.

Comment: note : I edited the code to include it directly

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

#define print(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

void validate(void* ptr, int value);
void validate(void* ptr, char* value);

int main() {

    //Int
    int variable1 = 5;
    validate(&variable1, variable1);
    //Float
    float variable2 = 5.5;
    validate(&variable2, variable2);
    //Double
    double variable3 = 5.56;
    validate(&variable3, variable3);
    //Char
    char* variable4 = "5";
    validate(&variable4, variable4);

    std::cin.get();
}

void validate(void* ptr, int value) {

    int* int_ptr = (int*)ptr;
    if(*int_ptr == value) {
        print("You entered in an integer");
    }else {
        print("Pls enter in an integer value");
    }
}

void validate(void* ptr, char* value) {
    print("Pls enter an integer value");
}
```

The output:
You entered in an integer
Pls enter in an integer value
Pls enter in an integer value
Pls enter an integer value

Comment: To implement it to your code you can create a while loop which depends on a bool variable which has to be initialized as true and when you finally enter an integer value you set it to false and your while loop will stop automatically. I hope it works fine for you!